# API response : StatusCode: 0, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0

Tags: c#, restsharp, rest-client

I am receiving Status code 0 when sent request from C#. But when I send the same request from Postman, I get status code 200.

Can you some help me, where it's going wrong?

```
       RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/");
        var request = new RestRequest(BaseAddress + "resource/afpd-eane?spot_id=9747", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("X-App-Token", Token);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        var resp = restClient.Execute(request);
```

Response:
StatusCode: 0, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}

Comment: Did you have postman generate the C# code?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the Postman request and response? What is the value of `BaseAddress` and `Token`?

Comment: The response should contain ErrorException and ErrorMessage be sure to look at these for the cause.  When I experience this issue it was because the request was timing out something that could only be established by looking at ErrorException.InnerException.Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `BaseAddress` when calling `RestRequest` constructor. That's redundant - base adress was passed to `RestClient` already. See the correct variant:

```
var request = new RestRequest("resource/afpd-eane?spot_id=9747", Method.GET);
```